# regex to get values between comma separated string

Tags: regex, string, vb.net, split, expression

I'm not to hot on regex, done a fair amount of googling but for some reason seem to be struggling on this. Basically I have a string as:

```
VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3,VALUE4
```

Now all want is a regex where I can say give me value 2 or give me value 3 etc.

I would have thought I could do something like this to get the 2nd value

```
,.*,,
```

This for last etc

```
,,,.*
```

There must be a simple solution to this...should also add this has to be done via regex!

Comment: What happens if one of your value contains a coma? Maybe you should look at using a proper CSV parser.

Comment: Ha just have to trust me they wont, need the regex :)

Comment: It depends on how the code using the regex uses the regex, e.g. "^.*?,(.*?),.*?,.*?$" would *capture* the second item.

Comment: and this would be fourth etc ^.*?,.*?,(.*?),.*?$ that is perfect ty sir :)

Comment: We can generalize this to `^(?:.*?,){2}(.*?),.*$` to capture, e.g., the third item.  It really depends on who is using this regex.

Comment: this gets the 3rd value but is not giving me the fourth https://regex101.com/r/N0r0Qh/1  presumed I could enter ^(?:.*?,){3}(.*?),.*$ and it would get me the last value, unless I've misunderstood

Comment: @MartinCooke Checkout [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N0r0Qh/2), and make sure your seat belt is fastened securely ^ ^.

Comment: haha holy poop, that's a beauty how'd you come up with that, works a charm ty :)

Comment: @MartinCooke That would be the *third* item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you need here is a regex split on the comma separator:

```
Dim input As String = "VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3,VALUE4"
Dim terms() As String = Regex.Split(input, ",\s*")
For Each term As String In terms
    Console.WriteLine(term)
Next
```

### Demo

Note that I split on `,\s*`, in case there might be some whitespace after each comma.

We *could* try to give you a raw regex which could extract a term in a given position, but even that would require knowing which tool you are using, to know how to access a capture group.  Since you're using VB.net, splitting the string using a regex is probably the way to go.

**Edit:**

From the comments, perhaps the following regex pattern is what you are looking for:

```
^(?:.*?,){3}(.*?)(?=,|$).*$
```

### Demo

Comment: many thanks for your response, I know its a bit odd but I won't be able to use that example as the application takes xml parameters, these being the string and then the regex to pull from the string if that's makes sense. I can't add vb.net code to the application I can only give the string values and the regex to tell the third party application which values I want collected.

Comment: @MartinCooke Then you need to at least tell me which regex tool/language your third party would be using.  Without telling us this, I'm afraid you are asking a question which needs to be closed as unclear.

Comment: the third party application is written in C#, we are aiming to inject this with string values and then the regex to tell it which values it should pick out, hope this helps :)

Comment: Doesn't really help.  I need to know the exact API being used.  Anyway, the answer I gave I believe is what most people with your problem in VB would actually want to use.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it better, do see Andrew Mortons response above and this appears to be working :)

Comment: using the above regex how would split on a | piped string?

Comment: @MartinCooke I'm guessing it would be `Regex.Split(input, "\|")`, but you also might need to double up the backslashes, e.g `Regex.Split(input, "\\|")`.

Comment: Sorry should of been more clear was after the regex but sussed it ^(?:.*?[|]){1}(.*?)(?=[|]|$).*$ many thanks for your help though, hope this helps others :)